# Android fontFamily sans-serif-light

Tags: android, android-layout, font-family

I need some clarification regarding sans-serif-light font for android. The following line of code

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
```

in custom style say `<style name="custom_style"/>` gives an ***error*** if minSdkVersion is less than 16.

but the same property directly on a textview

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
```

gives a ***warning*** if the minSdkVersion is less than 16.

Q1 What is the difference between the 2 approaches?

Q2 If i set the property directly in textview (2nd way) will the application be compatible with sdk version below 16 with the default font?

(I have only one device with android 4.4.4 and it works great on it with both ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i set the property directly in textview (2nd way) will the
>   application be compatible with sdk version below 16 with the default
>   font?

The behaviour should not change even if you set the font family in the styles. The difference is probably due to your Lint's settings.

Comment: That's what logic says, the behaviour should not change! But when i build the applcation 2nd way it sucsessfuly runs on  my device in contradiction to 1st way that results is a build fail. will the 1st way work for sdk < 16? and if it does, why so? and if not, why so?

Comment: If I were in you I would check the Lint settings to see if there some sort inconsistence. If you don't find anything wrong you can suppress  the error through `<item name="android:fontFamily" tools:ignore="NewApi"`, this way you can suppress the error and test in a device with sdk < 16

Comment: copy that. i will check the lint and get back in sometime

Answer (score 0):

As blackbelt said, it must be due to difference in lint settings.

San-serif light font will **NOT** work in devices below API 16. To fix this, you need to upload a custom font (.ttf file) file in asset.

---

Here is how to do it -

First copy the san-serif light font .ttf file to your asset folder which you can download from [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/sans%20serif). The file will contain many fonts but you just need san-serif light file.

Then in your code, do this -

```
Typeface light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "san-serif-light.ttf");
//Make sure that the font file's name is actually san-serif-light
```

Then you can set this to a textview this way -

```
textview.setTypeface(light);
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort! i know how to set a typeface and i know it will not work below 16. it would be nice if you can help me with the 2 sub questions.

Comment: Try checking in problem view for your error. This should give you a hint. If you don't find it in lint errors then let me know.